# React: How can I set my components' render content from outside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to do something like this (similar to the Accordion in react bootstrap):

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
   static Button;
   static Content;

   render(){
      return(
         <div>
            <Foo.Button/>
            <Foo.Content/>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

so that I can use it like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
     <Foo>
        <Foo.Button>
           <p>this is in the button</p>
        </Foo.Button>
        <Foo.Content>
           <p>this is content</p>
        </Foo.Content>
     </Foo>
  );
}
```

How can I get this or what do I have to search for an example?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the content you want via `props`. For example,

```
 return (
     <Foo>
        <Foo.Button>
           <p>{this.props.buttonText}</p>
        </Foo.Button>
        <Foo.Content>
           <p>{this.props.content}</p>
        </Foo.Content>
     </Foo>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  static Button;
  static Content;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Foo.Button />
        <Foo.Content />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Foo.Button = props => {
  const { children, ...rest } = props;

  <button {...rest}>{children}</button>;
};

Foo.Content = props => {
  const { children, ...rest } = props;

  <div {...rest}>{children}</div>;
};

export default Foo;
```

Comment: this did not work for me...  I put a return in front of the jsx elements of Foo.Button and Foo.Content so that I do not get a compile error but it still tells me that these props are undefined. Only thing I get is an empty button